# Query to fetch multiple fields in same column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql db.

```
     id | comment       
--------+--------------- 
   1121 |    Accounting
   1121 |    Shipping  
   1121 |    Receiving
   1121 |    Testing
   1122 |    Accounting
   1122 |    Receiving
```

I want to write such a query so that o/p will be like this-:

```
     id | comment       
--------+--------------- 
   1121 |    Accounting
   1121 |    Shipping  
   1121 |    Receiving
   1121 |    Testing
```

So I want Accounting, Shiping, Receiving and testing comments.

Can anybody plz guide me??

Comment: Which `id` do you want for comments that appear multiple times?

Comment: for id 1121 i need the comments.based on these comments i have to update another table

Comment: @Iswariya Suthakar:
Why did you decide for "Accounting" to select 1121 and not 1122? May be select 1122 instead of 1121? What is criteria?

Comment: I need to close the proccess for particular id if its having all comments which i said

Comment: Then why not simply specify a filter criterion using a `WHERE` clause:  e.g. `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1121`?

Comment: it is the process in product replacement. one person put accounting other will put shipping comments.... if all the comments there means i have to update the status as closed in another table.

Answer (score 1):

- If you only want the `id` of records that contain all four comments, you can group by `id` and filter such groups for those that contain the requisite number of records:

  ```
  SELECT   id
  FROM     my_table
  WHERE    comment IN ('Accounting', 'Shipping', 'Receiving', 'Testing')
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING   COUNT(*) = 4
  ```

  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a27/1/0).
- If you want the complete records for such `(id, comment)` pairs, you can join the result with your original table:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT   id
    FROM     my_table
    WHERE    comment IN ('Accounting', 'Shipping', 'Receiving', 'Testing')
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING   COUNT(*) = 4
  ) t
  WHERE comment IN ('Accounting', 'Shipping', 'Receiving', 'Testing')
  ```

  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a27/2/0).

Note that if your data model does not guarantee uniqueness of `(id, comment)` pairs, you will need to replace `COUNT(*)` with (the less performant) `COUNT(DISTINCT comment)` in the above queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to select all IDs, that have all 4 comments? In your example 1121 has 4 different comments (it's like a "state", right?), and 1122 has only 2 states (comments).

```
select T1.id from mytable T1, mytable T2, mytable T3, mytable T3 where T2.id=T1.id and T3.id=T1.id and T4.id=T1.id and T1.comment='Accounting' and T2.comment='Shipping' and T3.comment='Receiving' and T4.id='Shipping'
```

Comment: "no. i want for that particular id" - then it's trivial: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=1121

Comment: if i use this sometimes for that id it have only accounting and shipping or accounting, shipping like that but i want all the four comments. if all four comments are there i need to update status as closed in another table

Comment: Then my SQL above solves this problem. It finds only the IDs that have ALL 4 comments. Just replace "mytable" with your table name:  select T1.id from mytable T1, mytable T2, mytable T3, mytable T3 where T2.id=T1.id and T3.id=T1.id and T4.id=T1.id and T1.comment='Accounting' and T2.comment='Shipping' and T3.comment='Receiving' and T4.id='Shipping'